# Strip illegal characters in the subject line when sent email saved to local folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to save each email I send into a local folder. (These are then archived each month.)

I have code that works unless there are illegal characters in the subject line. I tried to insert code to strip illegal characters but always mess it up.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Call SaveACopy(Item)
End Sub


Sub SaveACopy(Item As Object)
    Const olMsg As Long = 3

    Dim m As MailItem
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim sSenderEmailAddress As String
    
    If TypeName(Item) <> "MailItem" Then Exit Sub

    Set m = Item

    savePath = "C:\Users\Email-SENT\"
    savePath = savePath & Format(Now(), "(yy.mm.dd-hh.NN ss) - ") & m.Subject & " (T) " & m.To
    savePath = savePath & ".msg"

    m.SaveAs savePath, olMsg

End Sub
```

Comment: Where are these illegal characters? In `m.Subject`?

Comment: Sorry, then would be within the subject line of the email, This code works 100% for me when I write an email but once I reply it always adds "RE:" to the subject and then starts the problem. I would ideally like to strip out "[\" & Chr(34) & "\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\=\+\|\[\]\{\}\`\'\;\:\<\>\?\/\,]" just incase any of these are within the subject line.

Comment: Do you want eliminate them, or replaced by another character (let us say "_")?

Comment: Replacing them with "_" would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next function. It offer the possibility to replace all the illegal characters with a common legal one. Or eliminate them:

```
Function ReplaceIllegChars(strClean As String, strChar As String) As String
    Dim strCharsToElim As String, i As Long, strSolved As String
    strCharsToElim = "~""#%&*:<>,@?{|}/\[]" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)

    For i = 1 To Len(strCharsToElim)
        strClean = Replace(strClean, Mid$(strCharsToElim, i, 1), strChar)
    Next

    ReplaceIllegChars = strClean
End Function
```

I am not the 'father' of the above function... I found it on internet some time before, added some other characters and personalized according to my need.

You may add other characters in `strCharsToElim`, too.

You can test it in the next way:

```
Sub testReplaceIllegChars()
     Dim x As String, strCorrect As String
     x = "<>,today,]|[%tomorrow\?@/"
     Debug.Print ReplaceIllegChars(x, "_")
     Debug.Print ReplaceIllegChars(x, "") 'to only replace them...
     strCorrect = ReplaceIllegChars(m.Subject, "_")
End Sub
```

In order to use it in your code, please replace the following code line:

```
savePath = savePath & Format(Now(), "(yy.mm.dd-hh.NN ss) - ") & m.Subject & " (T) " & m.To
```

with:

```
Dim strCorrect As String
strCorrect = ReplaceIllegChars(m.Subject, "_")
savePath = savePath & Format(Now(), "(yy.mm.dd-hh.NN ss) - ") & strCorrect & " (T) " & m.To
'your existing code...
```

Comment: @Craig Yellott Didn't you find some time to test the above function? If tested, didn't it solve your problem you asked about?

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, I tried the function and came up with other problems. Being so new to VBA I'm not sure I put the code in the correct location...

Comment: @Craig Yellott But I already suggested how to use it... Create a new variable `strCorrect`, call the function and use it instead of `m.Subject`. When have something not clear enough, you should ask for clarifications... I will edit my answer with a specific part to show you how to be adapted, if not clear the above explanation. I will do it, anyhow... Adapted. Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Sorry. me just being a dummy..... That works brilliantly thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @Craig Yellott Glad I could help! But I would like to remind that we here, when somebody answers our question, vote the answer up (if enough notoriety), and more important, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In such a way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the proposed solution works...

Answer (score 0):

You can use string-related functions available in VBA. For example, the [Replace function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function) returns a string, which is a substring of a string expression beginning at the start position (defaults to 1), in which a specified substring has been replaced with another substring a specified number of times. The return value of the `Replace` function is a string, with substitutions made, that begins at the position specified by start and concludes at the end of the expression string. It's not a copy of the original string from start to finish. So, you can strip out any illegal characters.

Also I'd suggest handling the `ItemAdd` of the `Items` class (which comes from the `Sent Items` folder) instead. The `ItemSend` event is fired when the item submitted but not being sent actually. So, any other software which handles the  `ItemSend` event may cancel any further processing by setting the `Cancel` parameter to true. But when the mail item was sent out in Outlook the sent item is put to the Sent Items folder. Actually, it can be any folder if you set the [SaveSentMessageFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.savesentmessagefolder) property which sets a `Folder` object that represents the folder in which a copy of the email message will be saved after being sent. For example:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim SentFolder As Folder
    Dim desFolder As Folder
 
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" And Item.DeleteAfterSubmit = False Then
       'Specify the sent emails
       If InStr(Item.To, "shirley") > 0 Or InStr(LCase(Item.Subject), "test") > 0 Then
          'Specify the folder for saving the sent emails
          'You can change it as per your needs
          Set SentFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
          Set desFolder = SentFolder.Folders("Test")
          Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = desFolder
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

So, then you could save sent items to the disk, not items that were submitted, but not sent yet.